# Condition for being a laplacian

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry

Let $P$ be a differential operator of order $2$ on $\mathbb R^d$. Is there a simple necessary and sufficient condition for which there exists a metric $g$ on $\mathbb R^d$ such that $P= \Delta_g$ where $\Delta_g$ is the Laplace Beltrami operator on $(\mathbb R^d, g)$ ?

Comment: An interesting question. Certainly ellipticity is a necessary condition.

Answer (score 1):

We can read off a compatibility condition from the coordinate form of $\Delta_g$:
$$
\Delta_g(f)=g^{ij}\partial_i(\partial_jf)-g^{ij}\Gamma^k{}_{ij}\partial_k(f)
$$
Working in coordinates, we can read the inverse metric (and thus the metric $g$) off of the second order part, and the compatibility condition is exactly that the first order part is equal to the expression above.